# Hovering menu doesnt resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu and a submenu , that will show only on mouse hover. But I cant resize it .

This is my javascript:

```
$('#menu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').hide();
});
```

HTML part:

```
      <ul id='menu'>

        <li>
           <a href="#"class="current">Marketing</a>
               <ul style="display:none; border-bottom-color:#F00;">
                  <li style="margin:-350px 294px 0px">
                      <a href="#" >ForSale</a>                     
                  </ul>
               </li>
       <!-- <li></li>-->
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[Demo is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/wfXZ4/1/)

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sub menu is not resized.i need resize submenu that mens width and heit will changed

Comment: look at your html first.. is not correct.. after that set it to 100% of its parents max- size

Comment: plese look at my fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/wfXZ4/1/.full code is available here.

Comment: If you want to change the Width and Height of sub-menu, define the same in CSS with some class like .submenu{ width: xx; height: xx;}

Comment: iam already tryed it but not got result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some changes here

```
  <ul class="submenu" style="width:60px; display:none; border-bottom-color:#F00;"><li style="margin:-328px 294px 0px"><a href="http://localhost/new_vinu_sir/Marketing.html" >ForSale</a>                     
                                    </ul></li>
```

and put css

```
.submenu li a
{ 
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

now the submenu is resized. You can resize as you wish.